# How to forward declare custom unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, forward-declaration

I have problems realizing a construct like the following. The idea is that I have a utility function defined in some header file which allocates some sort of resource. To relieve clients from the necessity to free it themselves, I'd like to wrap it into a smart pointer.
Unfortunately I somehow have to get the deleter type to the client and am having trouble forward-declaring it appropriately. My current solution looks like this, resulting in multiple definition errors because the deleter is re-defined with each additional include of utilities.h

Which is an elegant solution I'm looking for?

```
// utilities.h
namespace foo
{
  auto del = []( MyResource* res) { Deallocate( res ); };
  std::unique_ptr<MyResource, decltype(del)> getResource( );
}

// utilities.cpp
namespace foo
{
  std::unique_ptr<MyResource, decltype(foo::del)> getResource( )
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<MyResource, decltype(foo::del)>( Allocate( ), del );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the deleter a *function* instead of a lambda-object variable, and mark the function as `inline`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That should be an answer. OTOH, it prevents default-construction of such a `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a normal class instead of a lambda:

Header:

```
namespace foo {

  struct Deleter {
    void operator() (MyResource *res) const { Deallocate(res); }
  };

  std::unique_ptr<MyResource, Deleter> getResource();
}
```

Source:

```
namespace foo
{
  std::unique_ptr<MyResource, decltype(foo::del)> getResource( )
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<MyResource, Deleter>( Allocate( ) );
  }
}
```

This has the additional advantage of not having to specify the deleter when creating the pointer—a default-constructed `Deleter` will do just fine.

Comment: yep, your way is better

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend [Angew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33523852/2805305) over this mainly because of the extra overhead of type erasure in `std::function`. Is't good to know however that it is possible this way too.

---

The fix is simple: in headers have the declaration, in source have the definition:

```
// utilities.h
namespace foo {
  using del_t = std::function<void(MyResource *)>;
  extern  del_t del;
  std::unique_ptr<MyResource, del_t> getResource();
}

// utilities.cpp
namespace foo {
  del = [](MyResource* res) {
      Deallocate(res);
  };
  std::unique_ptr<MyResource, del_t> getResource() {
      return std::unique_ptr<MyResource, del_t>(Allocate(), del);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will bring in the extra overhead of type erasure in `std::function`.

Comment: @Angew yes. Don't know any other way to specify the type of a lambda. If that is a problem, he should go for a simple function.